# Phpexcel getting wrong date

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel to import excel document to website. I have problem with getting Date format.

Date format is dd.mm.Y but after getting cellValue I get samo random numbers ( float(42391) )

This is my code:

```
$datum = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
```

this shoud get date?

```
            $file_name = clean_uri($_FILES['excel']['name']);
            $file_name = 'povijest_'.$file_name;
            $folder_s = 'upload_data/excel';

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], '../'.$folder_s.'/'.$file_name);

            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../'.$folder_s.'/'.$file_name);
            $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true); 
            $highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
            $colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumm);
            $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet); 

for($i=4;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
                    $datum = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
                    $prva = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getValue();
                    $zadnja = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getValue();
                    $najvisa = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getValue();
                    $najniza = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F'.$i)->getValue();
                    $prosjecna = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G'.$i)->getValue();
                    $promjena = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H'.$i)->getValue();
                    $broj_transakcija = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I'.$i)->getValue();
                    $kolicina = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J'.$i)->getValue();
                    $promet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$i)->getValue();  

                    var_dump($datum); 
                    exit;
```

Comment: Why are you using `toArray()` to get a large array in `$allDataInSheet`, and then ignoring it?...... this is creating a big memory overhead, with no purpose

Answer (score 0):

It does get the date..... that isn't a random number, that's an MS Excel serialized datetime stamp. In the same way that you might use a unix timestamp in PHP, and then use the `date()` function to format that, MS Excel uses its own timestamp value, which is a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if created on a Mac). To display it formatted, you need to apply a number format mask.

The Cell's `getValue()` method will return the raw value from the cell, but `getFormattedValue()` will return the value with the number format mask applied

There are also documented methods (e.g. `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($msExcelSerializedTimestamp)`
) for converting between the MS Excel timestamp and unix timestamp or DateTime objects, and for checking whether a cell contains a date or not

Comment: You mean like this: " $datum = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getFormattedValue(); "  ??

I get error : " Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Cell::getFormattedValue() ... "

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getFormattedValue();` should work, if it tells you that the method doesn't exist, then it's lying, or you've mistyped..... but the beauty of Open Source is that you can look at the PHPExcel_Cell class and see for yourself the methods that are available because you have all the source there in front of you

Comment: Still getting same error. I tried to use something like this...

$timestamp = $datum/1000;
$test = date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);

I thought it was somekind of timestamp but i get wrong date.

Comment: It is some kind of timestamp as my answer explained...... it's an MS Excel timestamp which is NOT a unix timestamp, nor is it 1000 times a unix timestamp..... if `getFormattedValue()` doesn't work, then you have major problems anyway and heaven alone knows what you're running because it certainly isn't a standard version of PHPExcel. The alternative is to use the conversion functions that I mentioned: `$datum = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue()); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datum);`